# Accessing AWS via external editor (AWS CLI), authorization error although authorized

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, runtime-error, amazon-iam

I need to access a DynamoDB in AWS on my computer, where I have set up my credentials in AWS CLI. ALthough my provided user has the appropriate access authorization I get this error message, always when I have to get an Item from my database-table:

> User: arn:aws:iam::[user-number]:user/[username] is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:[user-number]:table/data_table_1 with an explicit deny

As already said, this user is authorized by the administrator to perform this request.
Maybe I am overseeing something or it has to do sth. with this "explicit deny".

I appreciate your help. Thanks

**For the Policies MFA must be present. So maybe I have to authorize myself with MFA device? How do I do that (if I am correct) via the AWS CLI?

Comment: `explicit deny` always takes priority over any allow. So if you have been given permissions to access the table, if there is any deny somewhere (your user, group, aws organization), it will be denied. You have to remove the deny first.

Comment: can i get a list of all denies I have amongst the policy groups?

Comment: Its not that easy. Deny may be part of inline policy, it can be from AWS organization, boundary permissions. Your aws admin should track down what's causing it.

Comment: I just saw that in the policy, where dynamodb:GetItem is allowed this is added: "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
                }
            }   --> does this mean I have to first authenticate myself with my MFA device via AWS CLI? If yes, how and which statement is needed for this?